# Find and count the results, delete if it is less than x

Tags: bash, find

I would like to search a directory and all its subdirectories for files that are structured like this: ABC.001.XYZ, ABC.001.DEF, ABC.002.XYZ and so fourth.
It should search for all files beginning with ABC.001, count the results, and if it is less than x, delete all files beginning with that. Then move on to ABC.002 and so on.

```
dir = X
counter=1
while [ $counter -le 500 ]
do
if [find ${dir} -type f -name 'ABC*' | wc -l -eq 5]
then
for file in $(find ${dir} -type f -name 'ABC*')
do
  /bin/rm -i ${file}
fi
((counter++))
done
```

My question is

I. how do I plug in the variable counter for -name 'ABC*' so it increments up. (Like a string placeholder)

II. How would I make it so if the counter is less than 10 or 100, I place 00 or 0 before the counter, so it would actually search for ABC001*, instead of ABC1*

Comment: So what's wrong with what you have there? What errors or unexpected behaviour are you getting?

Comment: Well first off, Im not quite sure how I would use string placeholder in bash, like I would use %s in c, so it searches for ABCCounter*. Also that would make it so it searches ABC1, ABC2, not ABC001 upto ABC500

Comment: Well bash has printf just like C. Your question is not very clear on what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Ok edited the post for clarity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `printf` to print formatted numbers as in most languages:

```
printf "ABC%03d" "$counter"
```

Simple substitution can put this into the arguments to `find`. Also worth mentioning that `find` can delete files directly, and just personal preference, but a `for` loop is probably neater.

```
#!/bin/bash
dir=X
for counter in $(seq 1 500); do
    if [[ $(find "$dir" -type f -name "$(printf "ABC%03d" "$counter")" | wc -l) -eq 5 ]]; then
        find "$dir" -type f -name "$(printf "ABC%03d" "$counter")" -delete
    fi
done
```

Comment: Sorry, now it gives conditional binary operator expected, syntax error near `"$dir"'...

Comment: Thanks, I had to remove the "" around $dir and $(printf...) but that did the trick!

Comment: You should always quote variables. If there are spaces in file names you'll be in a heap of trouble.